# In an Angular page containing custom components, how should I make sure all IDs are unique to get rid of the warnings?

Tags: html, angular

I have a custom component for text input and each of them has an internal field ID'ed as *data*. It causes the warning below to appear.

> [DOM] Found 13 elements with non-unique id #data

I'm clear on **why** it happens and I understand that's a warning not an actual error. I also recognize the appropriateness of an ID being unique (in its scope).

I'm not entirely sure regarding the implications in my particular case. In my opinion, warnings are tolerable but not acceptable.

Is there a best-practice approach to get rid of the error? By the very concept of a GP component, some parts will be alike in each instance. Or is there a trick to unique'fy the IDs? Or perhaps a directive or such to let Angular know we're cool with the state as is?

The component uses *@ViewChild("data")* to refer the input control in the template below.

```
<div id="outer">
  ...
  <label for="data">{{label}}</label>
  <input #data id="data" ... >
  <div *ngFor="let error of errors" class="row"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As you said it's only a warning it will not break your app. But it still not a good practice, I presume you have a ngFor that generate your template or you have call the component various time in the same parent.To use viewchild you don't need to put an id on your input ` <input #data />` Do you HAVE to use an id ? What is the point of using it ?

Comment: @Nico Not *ngFor*, just a bunch of textboxes. But for the sake of the argument, let's say it's an iterator there. The *#data* ID is in the template for the textbox, not in the template of the page that contains the textboxes, just to be clear. I was under impression that I have to ID an element to be able to refer to it using *@ViewChild* directive. How else can I make Angular know which element I'm referring to?

Comment: HTML requires unique IDs. It's not a matter of opinion.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not sure if I understand your comment properly and I fear that I might have been unclear in my question. I **do not** in any way claim that it's valid to have non-unique IDs in HTML. In fact, the point of my question is to investigate how to get rid of the warnings. (It's an empirical fact that the page works despite non-unique IDs, rendering my issue a nice-to-have rather than must-have, though.) Would you be willing to elaborate, please?

Comment: @Nico Did you see the comment? I'm afraid that it didn't notify you bacause I have multiple @'s in it.   :)

Comment: I only get the last notif. #data in your component it's the way of refering to it in your typescript. We need more informations about what you want to achieve.  if you have multiple input withe the ref #data you will have to use `@ViewChildren` directives instead of `@ViewChild`. And to get rid of the warning you can just use class instead of id. `input #data` is diffrent  is different than `input id ="data"`

Comment: @Nico Thanks for getting back to me. The *#data* is present only once in the *app-textbox* component's template. However, there's a component that has multiple instances of the *app-textbox* control in its template. That page complains about multiple IDs being non-unique.

Comment: @KonradViltersten The page "works" because browsers are smart enough to handle it, but they do so by breaking your page. Just like they'll auto-close a `<p>` element where one has illegal content or is closed improperly, they will simply not apply the ID for consideration to all the elements you tried to include it in. Use another attribute like `class` if you want multiple elements to have the same value for it. And as always, warnings are there for a reason (which is not "to be ignored").

Comment: @TylerH I do know that. In fact, that's the point of my question - to get rid of the warnings, so you seem to be preaching to the quire. I don't want to have the same naming on all the elements, like I said before. It's an implication of Angular putting the IDs in due to me using the templates that do have an ID in each instance of their usage. The question is literally what to do about it. Do you have a constructive suggestion **what** I should do (rather than  stating **that** I should do something)?

Comment: As far as I understand the purpose of using ids is querying it inside of Angular. You could use a directive or another attribite to query without any warnings. Also you could make a kind of wrapper which would apply common ID to input and its label and just concat uuid and id you want to use. But if it's only about querying just choose another attributy. For example `data-id` or `data-qa` whatever gives you an ability to query and have no errors at the same time. Just in case `@ViewChild("data")` refers to `#data` and not `id="data"` whilst you may wrap input with label tag

Comment: @Sergey Oh my god! This is a major fucktard moment. I totally, entirely and retardedly thought that the error is due to *#data* being transpiled to *id="data"* in the browser. And so I thought that the warnings are due to *#data*, hence asking how to resolve that. Oh, boy, this is embarrassing big time. And it's so stupid that, although the formulation of the question is technically valid, the community got mislead not believing that an experienced dev could by that idiotically confused. Well... I showed you there, hehehe. Please post your comment as an answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the purpose of using ids is querying it inside of Angular. You could use a directive or another attribute to query without any warnings. Also you could make a kind of wrapper which would apply common ID to input and its label and just concat UUID and ID you want to use. But if it's only about querying just choose another attribute. For example *data-id* or *data-qa* whatever gives you an ability to query and have no errors at the same time. Just in case `@ViewChild("data")` refers to `#data` and not `id="data"` whilst you may wrap input with label tag.